# How to use QDwm in Qt gui application

Tags: c++, qt, aero-glass

How can i use the QDwm to extend the aero glass in qt window? I don't found any documentation of how to do this. Link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/qdwm/

Answer (score 0):

Download the source code and look at QCustomWindow.hh. There are only 10 methods plus a constructor. You should be able to see what the methods do just by looking at their titles. Here they are:

```
// constructor
QCustomWindow(QWidget* parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = Qt::Window);

// setters
void setFrameRemoved(bool isRemoved);
void setExtraMargins(const QMargins& margins);
void setBorderSize(int size);
void setTitleBarSize(int size);

// getters
bool isFrameRemoved(void) const;
QMargins extraMargins(void) const;
int borderSize(void) const;
int titleBarSize(void) const;

static bool isAeroActivated(void);
static bool isThemeActivated(void);
```